# DEPENDENT_SYSTEM_CALL_FAILED error flipkart marketplace API

Tags: java, api, marketplace, flipkart-api

i am trying to fetching orders from flipkart, right now i am using search API of orders on which we can provide fromDate toDate etc for filtering but as i run that API on production environment i.e-:

> https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/v2/orders/search

it gives me following error:-

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "type": "SERVER_ERROR",
      "code": "DEPENDENT_SYSTEM_CALL_FAILED",
      "message": "A call to dependent system failed. Please retry after some time.",
      "params": null
    }
  ]
}
```

i don't know where i am doing wrong or there is any improvement they are doing on server side that's why the error is coming.

Please help me out from this issue.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You should wait. Seems to be an internal error of the system, see "Please retry after some time." Or contact the server provider or check the blog/news section for temporary problems.

Comment: @Konrad thanks for quick reply i already raised an issue to the support team but didn't got reply from there side yet.

Comment: This is server error, Flipkart Api are very inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

I have added below code

```
request.AddJsonBody(yourobject);
```

where yourobject is custom object you have initialized. request is RestSharp request.

I have invoked request asynchronously as below

```
client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => {
            MessageBox.Show(response.Content);
        });
```

Comment: where to use this set of code. Can u brief your answer??

Comment: @Sunil Pandey can you please help me out I am also getting the same error!